# React Native: How to get android StatusBar height

Tags: android, react-native

i'm trying to get the window dimensions with React Native, but it gives me the dimension with the StatusBar height, i need to substract it.

How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

RESOLVED

We can get the StatusBar height in this way:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
console.log(StatusBar.currentHeight)
```

This only works on Android.

Comment: Actionbar !== statusbar